# Could an extremely powerful solar flare erase human memories?

Tags: science-fiction

The famous Carrington event in mid 19th century caused disruption of telegraphic lines. Many operators witnessed that the telegraph worked even though it was proveably out of power.

In today's technocentric society, the effect of Carrington-like solar flare would be devastating. All electric power lines and electronic devices (or for at least 1/2 of the globe) could be out of service in a second. Also, many data storages, since they work using the principles of electromagnetism (like magnetic tapes) could be erased or damaged.

Is a reasonable deduction that since brains are as well electromagnetic devices, that they can also be affected? Could a solar flare cause human brain to forgot something already remembered?

Comment: brains work with chemical releases, which produce electromagnetic waves.... this doesn't make brains electromagnetic devices. Muscles work with chemical signals, and they produce thermal energy, this doesn't mean muscles are radiators.

Comment: and the answer is likely going to be NO. Memory is not a wave but a path between different neurons. To erase memories you have to destroy the  path. Like destroying a highroad or alternatively destroy the neurons. Some long therm memories can't be destroyed as they are stored and copied in multiple places in the body, some even in the DNA.

Comment: Brains are chemical devices. They produce electromagnetic noise as a side effect of their mode of operation. It is similar how computers produce heat as a side effect of their operation, although they are not thermal engines. (And the effects of a solar flare would **not** be quite so devastatingl. The arrival of charged particles etc. is predictable some days in advance; in the case of such an event, power distribution networks would be shut down in a safe manner, devices would be disconnected and afterwards the operation would resume safely. We do have electrical engineers on duty.)

Comment: I think this is a cool idea.  Sidestepping all the electrical chaos would be to have the memory wipe produced by [earth lights](http://inamidst.com/lights/earth)

Comment: Maybe this could be set in the near future where almost everybody had a chip in their head as a brain computer interface, you could then use this combined with a solar flare to explain memory loss

Comment: Sure. A dead body produced a dead brain, which probably doesn't have any memories.

Answer (score 5):

> since brains are as well electromagnetic devices

I would not state that. Brains are all but IC with transistors in it to operate their logic. To quote someone, "if our brain was simple enough that we could understand it, we would be too stupid to understand it".

The devastating effects of events like the Carrington event on electronic devices come from the induced currents produced by large variation of magnetic field. Our brains do not have loops of conductive material where a varying magnetic field can induce currents. If our brains could be affected by changing magnetic field, we would be affected by being close to strong moving magnets, lightning and so on. A radio is disturbed by a nearby lightning, not our brain.

Answer (score 3):

**Brains and electromagnetism**

Brains aren't really electromagnetism things. Even if you would classify them as such, the effect is so negligible it won't work.

Biological connections are very difficult to affect by electromagnetism. As an example, we have MRI machines. They employ powerful electromagnets, super cooled to near 0° (Kelvin!). Together with a huge energy consumption it creates insanely big magnetic fields. If you enter/move through these fields, you definitely feel things throughout your body. The iron in your blood will react, which can be detected by the MRI to make a 3D picture. Yet there are no memory side effects. So even if your Carrington event put an energy content in the atmosphere that is stronger than a point blank powerful MRI on a global scale, you'll still not have a mind blank.

The reason is that we don't store things electronically in our brain. No or barely any magnetic or metal parts are used, so they can barely be influenced. Compare that to a flash drive, hard drive, old cassette or the like can each be influenced by electromagnetism or induction. They are able to be affected because of how they work, which is simply different from neurons.

Although there is still no certainty, the most accepted theory is that we store information by having certain neuron connections activate in a certain electrical rhythm. Electromagnetism can't be induced into the neurons, and if it could it wouldn't alter the neurons. Not until induction would start to destroy the neurons. Only by removing the neural connections you can conceivably remove memory. So after a Carrington event, if it would affect us, we could remember everything normally.

I say normslly, but yhat is only if you survive without damage. If you are able to induce such electrostorms in the brain but not break the neurons, you'll effectively have a full brain epilepsy. Imagine a normal epilepsy, but now include breathing, heart rate, sweating and more into the equation. The mind blank is there for most people, as they'll likely die.

A mind wipe with electromagnetism is impossible, leading to other problems even if you could.

Answer (score 1):

**No**

As others have mentioned, while electricity is involved with the human brain and nervous system — the system is predominantly chemical in nature. An event large enough to disrupt the electro-chemical processes of the brain would kill the body before what happened in the brain mattered.

It's worth noting that while the [Carrington event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrington_Event) was, indeed, devastating — our modern world is not nearly as susceptible. Yes, we have orders of magnitude more wires out there, but we also have fuses and breakers everywhere, substantially better grounding, and electrostatic discharge controls (ESD) built into most integrated circuits.

Is all that protection perfect? Heck no. Similar effects are caused locally by lightening strikes. In my own experience, a strike that burned wires inside the walls of my house and fried a printer had no effect on the rest of the house or on the computer the printer was connected to due to all those breakers, fuses, grounding, and ESD circuits. A modern Carrington event would be nasty, but not as devastating to our world today as it was to the world of yesteryear.  Don't get me wrong, I firmly believe that Mother Nature can prove the arrogance of humanity at her convenience... but we haven't been sitting idle, either.

Answer (score 0):

## No.

> In today's technocentric society, the effect of Carrington-like solar flare would be devastating. All electric power lines and electronic devices (or for at least 1/2 of the globe) could be out of service in a second.

Not quite. It would be, if the Carrington event hadn't happened. But it has. Since then, land lines have protections from geomagnetic storms.

> Also, many data storages, since they work using the principles of electromagnetism (like magnetic tapes) could be erased or damaged.

Definitely not. A solar flare causes *geomagnetic currents*, but the *magnetic* effects of those are negligible. The involved field strength is in the low Gauss range, two to three orders of magnitude less than a fridge magnet.

> Is a reasonable deduction that since brains are as well electromagnetic devices, that they can also be affected?

*A priori*, it would. But are brains electromagnetic devices? Evidence seems to point to the contrary. A *rapidly vibrating* magnetic field can influence the brain (a little) through current induction and ionic interference, but a solar flare wouldn't do that.

Moreover, we *do* know from observation that while human brains immersed in a field in the high Tesla range (e.g. a NMR machine) do appear to perceive *something*, this isn't enough by far to induce anything detectable at the neurological level.

And a flare event capable of inducing Tesla-range fields on the surface of the Earth would be something unimaginably catastrophic - nothing less than the Sun going nova could do so much, and I'm not really sure a nova would be enough (also, the Sun couldn't nova).